# What to use for typedef struct array in c++

Tags: c++

I have been implementing a visual debugger in my application using another bit of source code. I ran into an issue when I stumbled across them using this..

```
struct DebugVertex
{
    gkVector3 v;
    unsigned int color;
};


typedef utArray<DebugVertex> Buffer;
```

I found the free library that they are using for utArray, however I like to stick with the included libraries when possible (it seems like they used external libs just cause). This is what the definition of utArray looks like...

```
template <typename T>
class utArray
{
public:
    typedef T           *Pointer;
    typedef const T     *ConstPointer;

    typedef T            ValueType;
    typedef const T      ConstValueType;

    typedef T           &ReferenceType;
    typedef const T     &ConstReferenceType;

    typedef utArrayIterator<utArray<T> >       Iterator;
    typedef const utArrayIterator<utArray<T> > ConstIterator;

public:
    utArray() : m_size(0), m_capacity(0), m_data(0), m_cache(0)  {}

    utArray(const utArray<T>& o)
        : m_size(o.size()), m_capacity(0), m_data(0), m_cache(0)
    {
        reserve(m_size);
        copy(m_data, o.m_data, m_size);
    }
```

Is there anything similar I can use? I am not experienced defining a type based on a struct array so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Thanks for taking the time to format your question.

Comment: Not a problem, I have an account but I can't remember my information. Wanted to note I know I have only included a small portion of the definition, just hoping someone might recognize it and know what could be used in its place.

Comment: It would be useful to see what `m_cache` is. Apart from that, it looks very much like `std::vector`, the standard dynamic array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all standard sequence STL containers probably `vector` & `deque` are closest to an array (at least to me, I associate random access with arrays...).

The only problem you would have is that STL containers have different naming conventions for the internal typedefs like: iterator, pointer, value type & so on. If you really like typing `Buffer::Iterator` instead of `Buffer::iterator` then you'll need to have a proxy type over the STL type of your choosing. Something like:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class utArray
{
private:
   typedef std::vector<T>                             InnerContainer;
   InnerContainer                                     m_innerContainer;

public:
   typedef typename InnerContainer::pointer           Pointer;
   typedef typename const InnerContainer::pointer     ConstPointer;

   typedef typename InnerContainer::value_type        ValueType;
   typedef const typename InnerContainer::value_type  ConstValueType;

   typedef typename InnerContainer::reference         ReferenceType;
   typedef typename InnerContainer::const_reference   ConstReferenceType;

   typedef typename InnerContainer::iterator          Iterator;
   typedef typename InnerContainer::const_iterator    ConstIterator;

public:
   utArray() {}

   utArray(const utArray<T>& o)
      : m_innerContainer(o.m_innerContainer)
   {
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like a std::vector to me ... (`#include <vector>`)

Comment: Proactively fixed formatting for you.  (Sorry if that was annoying.)